# how to write href <a href="#men">Men Category</a> link in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

For my WordPress theme I need help from an expert. Here is my nav-list html

Example:

```js
//Here is my WP code:

<li>
<?php 
    $category_men = get_the_category_by_id($catmen['content-cat-one']);
 
    $content_one =new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'category_name' => $category_men
 ));
          
 while($content_one->have_posts()) : $content_one->the_post(); ?>
 <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $catmen['content-cat-one'] ); ?>#<?php echo get_cat_ID($category_men); ?>" >Men Category</a> 
 <?php endwhile; ?>   
 </li>
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#men">Men Category</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-pane active" id="men">
</div>


<div class="tab-pane active" id="<?php echo get_cat_ID($category_men); ?>">
```

The result comes out: `//localhost/my-themes/category/featured/#5`

I do not want the result above, I want `//localhost/my-themes/category/featured/`

How to overcome these problems?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code,

```
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $catmen['content-cat-one'] ); ?>#<?php echo get_cat_ID($category_men); ?>" >Men Category</a>
```

with the code snippet bellow.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $catmen['content-cat-one'] ); ?>">Men Category</a>
```

Comment: Hi Ajith: replace code will not help me.
in order to work what about below code. when mouse over the category below content will have shown.

<div class="tab-pane active" id="<?php echo get_cat_ID($category_men); ?>">

Comment: so you will have to write some jquery code to load contents to said div.

Comment: already jquery. its loaded. its working like: 
http://localhost/my-themes/category/featured/#5
without hash ( # ) not working.
How to get it like http://localhost/my-themes/category/featured/ ?
any idea!